# How to get City and Country using HTML5 Geolocation without relying on Google API?

Tags: html, geolocation

This may seem unorthodox, but what I want to do is get a persons entire city, state(or province) and country based on his or her input. I want to do this without using Google API as this project I am working on is a commercial project and as per Google's TOS I need to pay $10,000 to use it for commercial purposes (which is a pretty steep price for how often I would be using it i.e. 1-5 times a week).

Sample Input: Toronto
Return: Toronto, Ontario, Canada

Sample Input2: Vancouver
Return: Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada

Sample Input3: Otawwa (notice the typo)
Return: Ottawa, Ontario, Canada

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only location info you can get from geolocation api is longitude and latitude. However, you could use this info to query a database and return the info you need. There are many free geo location databases on the internet. Google "free geolocation database" and just use any that you see fit. They usually come in a big data file that you need to import to your own database. After that, you just can just call your own ajax service to get results fast and free.
Alternatively, you can find the location by using their IP, if you need to code this on the server and not the client, again, there are free IP databases for this, too. I've used http://www.ipligence.com/ to query IP locations and it worked fine. They have free version.

Answer (score 0):

My friend and I put this together, we use standard government data, and tie it to google maps.

http://nwstartups.com/api/geo/country.php

Will